# CKEditor / wysiwyg for public profile

Tags: ckeditor

I have a custom data field that is a profile that I'm sharing via the frontend of my web site (to Registered users).

I'm using Joomla 3.8.x and civiCRM 5.10.0 -- I've set the custom field as "Note Rich Text Editor" but when include the field in a profile to allow registered users to complete the field, the editor doesn't appear -- just a text box.

Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 1):

[civicrm.root] wrongly evaluated on Joomla. See: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/issues/5

A fix for your particular issue is:
Create an override file in your Custom PHP Directory for CRM/Core/Resources.php

On Line: 738 
CHANGE:

```
'wysisygScriptLocation' => Civi::paths()->getUrl("[civicrm.root]/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js"),
```

TO:

```
'wysisygScriptLocation' => Civi::paths()->getUrl(Civi::settings()->get('userFrameworkResourceURL')."/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js"),
```